# Problem with Animated gif on Android

Tags: android, animated-gif

I need some advice about animation. I have an animated GIF, but how to put in Android app to be animation. When I put it doesn't move at all. I read something about animation in Android and I need to have pictures for animation. Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 5):

Android does not support animated GIFs much. You can use an [`AnimationDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html), perhaps defined from frames using a [drawable XML file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame).

Comment: I extract gif to png pictures with gif2png and it works with XML ! Thanks for advice !

Comment: it supports but it's way more complicated to use that then frame animation

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996878/showing-gif-image-with-library. How can I implement it with library

Comment: @CommonsWare Sir, what should be do for the url gif ? means which library is helpful Glide OR Ion..Or there much more better library from this two libarary......Could you please help me

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using GIF image in your app as Splash screen.
Android does not support animated GIFs. so extract gif to png pictures with gif2png and it works with XML.
And Other Option Adding gif image in an ImageView in android
[Adding gif image in an ImageView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

100 % Work...

1) Add Glide library dependency...

```
   compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
```

2)

```
   imageView = findViewById(R.id.gifImage);
```

3)

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .asGif()
            .load(R.drawable.gifImage)
            .into(imageView);
```

just use .asGif() before .load()