# Adding gif image in an ImageView in android

Tags: android, imageview, gif

I added an animated gif image in an imageView. I am not able to view it as a gif image. No animation is there. It's appearing just as a still image. I would like to know how can i show it as a gif image.

Comment: Please check below link may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/android-display-animated-gif http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691726/problem-with-animated-gif-on-android

Comment: Use this link its simple/easy to use and best. [http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.com/2014/04/animated-gif-imageview-library-for.html](http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.com/2014/04/animated-gif-imageview-library-for.html)

Comment: if you exactly want to add gif image into imageview only ,not in webview than use this its work fine for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/29488519/3514144

Comment: here is the answer link to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35147375/gif-support-in-react-native-android/40717833#40717833

Answer (score 86, accepted):

First, copy your GIF image into Asset Folder of your app
create following classes and paste the code
**AnimationActivity: -**

```
public class AnimationActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = getAssets().open("piggy.gif");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
          GifWebView view = new GifWebView(this, "file:///android_asset    /piggy.gif");                 

    setContentView(view);
}
}
```

**GifDecoder:-**

```
public class GifDecoder {

    public static final int STATUS_OK = 0;

    public static final int STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR = 1;

    public static final int STATUS_OPEN_ERROR = 2;

    protected static final int MAX_STACK_SIZE = 4096;
    protected InputStream in;
    protected int status;
    protected int width; // full image width
    protected int height; // full image height
    protected boolean gctFlag; // global color table used
    protected int gctSize; // size of global color table
    protected int loopCount = 1; // iterations; 0 = repeat forever
    protected int[] gct; // global color table
    protected int[] lct; // local color table
    protected int[] act; // active color table
    protected int bgIndex; // background color index
    protected int bgColor; // background color
    protected int lastBgColor; // previous bg color
    protected int pixelAspect; // pixel aspect ratio
    protected boolean lctFlag; // local color table flag
    protected boolean interlace; // interlace flag
    protected int lctSize; // local color table size
    protected int ix, iy, iw, ih; // current image rectangle
    protected int lrx, lry, lrw, lrh;
    protected Bitmap image; // current frame
    protected Bitmap lastBitmap; // previous frame
    protected byte[] block = new byte[256]; // current data block
    protected int blockSize = 0; // block size last graphic control extension info
    protected int dispose = 0; // 0=no action; 1=leave in place; 2=restore to bg; 3=restore to prev
    protected int lastDispose = 0;
    protected boolean transparency = false; // use transparent color
    protected int delay = 0; // delay in milliseconds
    protected int transIndex; // transparent color index
    // LZW decoder working arrays
    protected short[] prefix;
    protected byte[] suffix;
    protected byte[] pixelStack;
    protected byte[] pixels;
    protected Vector<GifFrame> frames; // frames read from current file
    protected int frameCount;

    private static class GifFrame {
            public GifFrame(Bitmap im, int del) {
                    image = im;
                    delay = del;
            }

            public Bitmap image;
            public int delay;
    }


    public int getDelay(int n) {
            delay = -1;
            if ((n >= 0) && (n < frameCount)) {
                    delay = frames.elementAt(n).delay;
            }
            return delay;
    }


    public int getFrameCount() {
            return frameCount;
    }


    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
            return getFrame(0);
    }


    public int getLoopCount() {
            return loopCount;
    }
    protected void setPixels() {

            int[] dest = new int[width * height];

            if (lastDispose > 0) {
                    if (lastDispose == 3) {
                            // use image before last
                            int n = frameCount - 2;
                            if (n > 0) {
                                    lastBitmap = getFrame(n - 1);
                            } else {
                                    lastBitmap = null;
                            }
                    }
                    if (lastBitmap != null) {
                            lastBitmap.getPixels(dest, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                            if (lastDispose == 2) {
                                    // fill last image rect area with background color
                                    int c = 0;
                                    if (!transparency) {
                                            c = lastBgColor;
                                    }
                                    for (int i = 0; i < lrh; i++) {
                                            int n1 = (lry + i) * width + lrx;
                                            int n2 = n1 + lrw;
                                            for (int k = n1; k < n2; k++) {
                                                    dest[k] = c;
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
            int pass = 1;
            int inc = 8;
            int iline = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ih; i++) {
                    int line = i;
                    if (interlace) {
                            if (iline >= ih) {
                                    pass++;
                                    switch (pass) {
                                    case 2:
                                            iline = 4;
                                            break;
                                    case 3:
                                            iline = 2;
                                            inc = 4;
                                            break;
                                    case 4:
                                            iline = 1;
                                            inc = 2;
                                            break;
                                    default:
                                            break;
                                    }
                            }
                            line = iline;
                            iline += inc;
                    }
                    line += iy;
                    if (line < height) {
                            int k = line * width;
                            int dx = k + ix; // start of line in dest
                            int dlim = dx + iw; // end of dest line
                            if ((k + width) < dlim) {
                                    dlim = k + width; // past dest edge
                            }
                            int sx = i * iw; // start of line in source
                            while (dx < dlim) {
                                    // map color and insert in destination
                                    int index = ((int) pixels[sx++]) & 0xff;
                                    int c = act[index];
                                    if (c != 0) {
                                            dest[dx] = c;
                                    }
                                    dx++;
                            }
                    }
            }
            image = Bitmap.createBitmap(dest, width, height, Config.ARGB_4444);
    }
    public Bitmap getFrame(int n) {
            if (frameCount <= 0)
                    return null;
            n = n % frameCount;
            return ((GifFrame) frames.elementAt(n)).image;
    }
    public int read(InputStream is) {
            init();
            if (is != null) {
                    in = is;
                    readHeader();
                    if (!err()) {
                            readContents();
                            if (frameCount < 0) {
                                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                            }
                    }
            } else {
                    status = STATUS_OPEN_ERROR;
            }
            try {
                    is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return status;
    }      
    protected void decodeBitmapData() {
            int nullCode = -1;
            int npix = iw * ih;
            int available, clear, code_mask, code_size, end_of_information, in_code, old_code, bits, code, count, i, datum, data_size, first, top, bi, pi;
            if ((pixels == null) || (pixels.length < npix)) {
                    pixels = new byte[npix]; // allocate new pixel array
            }
            if (prefix == null) {
                    prefix = new short[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
            }
            if (suffix == null) {
                    suffix = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
            }
            if (pixelStack == null) {
                    pixelStack = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE + 1];
            }                
            data_size = read();
            clear = 1 << data_size;
            end_of_information = clear + 1;
            available = clear + 2;
            old_code = nullCode;
            code_size = data_size + 1;
            code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
            for (code = 0; code < clear; code++) {
                    prefix[code] = 0; // XXX ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
                    suffix[code] = (byte) code;
            }               
            datum = bits = count = first = top = pi = bi = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < npix;) {
                    if (top == 0) {
                            if (bits < code_size) {
                                    // Load bytes until there are enough bits for a code.
                                    if (count == 0) {
                                            // Read a new data block.
                                            count = readBlock();
                                            if (count <= 0) {
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                            bi = 0;
                                    }
                                    datum += (((int) block[bi]) & 0xff) << bits;
                                    bits += 8;
                                    bi++;
                                    count--;
                                    continue;
                            }                               
                            code = datum & code_mask;
                            datum >>= code_size;
                            bits -= code_size;                               
                            if ((code > available) || (code == end_of_information)) {
                                    break;
                            }
                            if (code == clear) {
                                    // Reset decoder.
                                    code_size = data_size + 1;
                                    code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
                                    available = clear + 2;
                                    old_code = nullCode;
                                    continue;
                            }
                            if (old_code == nullCode) {
                                    pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                                    old_code = code;
                                    first = code;
                                    continue;
                            }
                            in_code = code;
                            if (code == available) {
                                    pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                                    code = old_code;
                            }
                            while (code > clear) {
                                    pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                                    code = prefix[code];
                            }
                            first = ((int) suffix[code]) & 0xff;
                            if (available >= MAX_STACK_SIZE) {
                                    break;
                            }
                            pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                            prefix[available] = (short) old_code;
                            suffix[available] = (byte) first;
                            available++;
                            if (((available & code_mask) == 0) && (available < MAX_STACK_SIZE)) {
                                    code_size++;
                                    code_mask += available;
                            }
                            old_code = in_code;
                    }
                    // Pop a pixel off the pixel stack.
                    top--;
                    pixels[pi++] = pixelStack[top];
                    i++;
            }
            for (i = pi; i < npix; i++) {
                    pixels[i] = 0; // clear missing pixels
            }
    }        
    protected boolean err() {
            return status != STATUS_OK;
    }       
    protected void init() {
            status = STATUS_OK;
            frameCount = 0;
            frames = new Vector<GifFrame>();
            gct = null;
            lct = null;
    }        
    protected int read() {
            int curByte = 0;
            try {
                    curByte = in.read();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            }
            return curByte;
    }       
    protected int readBlock() {
            blockSize = read();
            int n = 0;
            if (blockSize > 0) {
                    try {
                            int count = 0;
                            while (n < blockSize) {
                                    count = in.read(block, n, blockSize - n);
                                    if (count == -1) {
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    n += count;
                            }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (n < blockSize) {
                            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                    }
            }
            return n;
    }        
    protected int[] readColorTable(int ncolors) {
            int nbytes = 3 * ncolors;
            int[] tab = null;
            byte[] c = new byte[nbytes];
            int n = 0;
            try {
                    n = in.read(c);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (n < nbytes) {
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            } else {
                    tab = new int[256]; // max size to avoid bounds checks
                    int i = 0;
                    int j = 0;
                    while (i < ncolors) {
                            int r = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                            int g = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                            int b = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                            tab[i++] = 0xff000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
                    }
            }
            return tab;
    }       
    protected void readContents() {
            // read GIF file content blocks
            boolean done = false;
            while (!(done || err())) {
                    int code = read();
                    switch (code) {
                    case 0x2C: // image separator
                            readBitmap();
                            break;
                    case 0x21: // extension
                            code = read();
                            switch (code) {
                            case 0xf9: // graphics control extension
                                    readGraphicControlExt();
                                    break;
                            case 0xff: // application extension
                                    readBlock();
                                    String app = "";
                                    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                                            app += (char) block[i];
                                    }
                                    if (app.equals("NETSCAPE2.0")) {
                                            readNetscapeExt();
                                    } else {
                                            skip(); // don't care
                                    }
                                    break;
                            case 0xfe:// comment extension
                                    skip();
                                    break;
                            case 0x01:// plain text extension
                                    skip();
                                    break;
                            default: // uninteresting extension
                                    skip();
                            }
                            break;
                    case 0x3b: // terminator
                            done = true;
                            break;
                    case 0x00: // bad byte, but keep going and see what happens break;
                    default:
                            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                    }
            }
    }      
    protected void readGraphicControlExt() {
            read(); // block size
            int packed = read(); // packed fields
            dispose = (packed & 0x1c) >> 2; // disposal method
            if (dispose == 0) {
                    dispose = 1; // elect to keep old image if discretionary
            }
            transparency = (packed & 1) != 0;
            delay = readShort() * 10; // delay in milliseconds
            transIndex = read(); // transparent color index
            read(); // block terminator
    }       
    protected void readHeader() {
            String id = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    id += (char) read();
            }
            if (!id.startsWith("GIF")) {
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                    return;
            }
            readLSD();
            if (gctFlag && !err()) {
                    gct = readColorTable(gctSize);
                    bgColor = gct[bgIndex];
            }
    }        
    protected void readBitmap() {
            ix = readShort(); // (sub)image position & size
            iy = readShort();
            iw = readShort();
            ih = readShort();
            int packed = read();
            lctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 - local color table flag interlace
            lctSize = (int) Math.pow(2, (packed & 0x07) + 1);
            interlace = (packed & 0x40) != 0;
            if (lctFlag) {
                    lct = readColorTable(lctSize); // read table
                    act = lct; // make local table active
            } else {
                    act = gct; // make global table active
                    if (bgIndex == transIndex) {
                            bgColor = 0;
                    }
            }
            int save = 0;
            if (transparency) {
                    save = act[transIndex];
                    act[transIndex] = 0; // set transparent color if specified
            }
            if (act == null) {
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR; // no color table defined
            }
            if (err()) {
                    return;
            }
            decodeBitmapData(); // decode pixel data
            skip();
            if (err()) {
                    return;
            }
            frameCount++;
            // create new image to receive frame data
            image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_4444);
            setPixels(); // transfer pixel data to image
            frames.addElement(new GifFrame(image, delay)); // add image to frame
            // list
            if (transparency) {
                    act[transIndex] = save;
            }
            resetFrame();
    }
    protected void readLSD() {
            // logical screen size
            width = readShort();
            height = readShort();
            // packed fields
            int packed = read();
            gctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 : global color table flag
            // 2-4 : color resolution
            // 5 : gct sort flag
            gctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 : gct size
            bgIndex = read(); // background color index
            pixelAspect = read(); // pixel aspect ratio
    }       
    protected void readNetscapeExt() {
            do {
                    readBlock();
                    if (block[0] == 1) {
                            // loop count sub-block
                            int b1 = ((int) block[1]) & 0xff;
                            int b2 = ((int) block[2]) & 0xff;
                            loopCount = (b2 << 8) | b1;
                    }
            } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
    }       
    protected int readShort() {
            // read 16-bit value, LSB first
            return read() | (read() << 8);
    }
    protected void resetFrame() {
            lastDispose = dispose;
            lrx = ix;
            lry = iy;
            lrw = iw;
            lrh = ih;
            lastBitmap = image;
            lastBgColor = bgColor;
            dispose = 0;
            transparency = false;
            delay = 0;
            lct = null;
    }
    protected void skip() {
            do {
                    readBlock();
            } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
    }
}
```

**GifDecoderView:-**

```
public class GifDecoderView extends ImageView {

private boolean mIsPlayingGif = false;

private GifDecoder mGifDecoder;

private Bitmap mTmpBitmap;

final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (mTmpBitmap != null && !mTmpBitmap.isRecycled()) {
            GifDecoderView.this.setImageBitmap(mTmpBitmap);
        }
    }
};

public GifDecoderView(Context context, InputStream stream) {
    super(context);
    playGif(stream);
}

private void playGif(InputStream stream) {
    mGifDecoder = new GifDecoder();
    mGifDecoder.read(stream);

    mIsPlayingGif = true;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final int n = mGifDecoder.getFrameCount();
            final int ntimes = mGifDecoder.getLoopCount();
            int repetitionCounter = 0;
            do {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    mTmpBitmap = mGifDecoder.getFrame(i);
                    int t = mGifDecoder.getDelay(i);
                    mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(t);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(ntimes != 0) {
                    repetitionCounter ++;
                }
            } while (mIsPlayingGif && (repetitionCounter <= ntimes));
        }
    }).start();
}

public void stopRendering() {
    mIsPlayingGif = true;
}
}
```

**GifMovieView:-**

```
public class GifMovieView extends View {

private Movie mMovie;

private long mMoviestart;

public GifMovieView(Context context, InputStream stream) {
    super(context);

    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(stream);        
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if (mMoviestart == 0) { 
        mMoviestart = now;
    }

    final int relTime = (int)((now - mMoviestart) % mMovie.duration());
    mMovie.setTime(relTime);
    mMovie.draw(canvas, 10, 10);
    this.invalidate();
}
}
```

**GifWebView:-**

```
public class GifWebView extends WebView {

public GifWebView(Context context, String path) {
    super(context);        

    loadUrl(path);
}
}
```

**I Think It Might Help You...  :)**

Comment: basically you dont need all of that since you create decoders and comlex code and never use it! you are using GifWebView view = new GifWebView(this, "file:///android_asset    /piggy.gif"); which calls a subclass of webview which has no customization to webview, you can replace this whole code with 3 lines..
webView wView = new webView(this); wView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/piggy.gif");
setContentView(view);

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer..:) its working nice !! but I have one issue with webview (in GifWebView class) its displaying the gif file larger than the device screen. so how to provide custom width and height for that view OR else I can use any other view???

Comment: This will only play my gif once? It won't keep cycling through the gif??? Is there anyway I can re-run the methods to display it again?

Comment: please help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996878/showing-gif-image-with-library

Comment: This works for my device running on 4.4, but when I ran it on a Lollipop device (5.1) the Gif does not animate.

Comment: @AhmadDwaik'Warlock' thank you very much. I'm sick and tired from popular image library bugs: fresco plays gif slow, default `imageView` often crashes with OOM (I divide my gif on frames and tried to use `animation-list`). This is most laconic solution!

Comment: that's toooooooo looooooooong to do

Comment: when using webview nl need to use the whole other codes, to use the decider long code you need to do         InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = getAssets().open("gif1.gif");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
          GifDecoderView view = new GifDecoderView(this, stream);                 
linear1.addView(view);

Comment: Why aren't all gif files with animation displayed correctly? After GifDecoder, some textures have only the upper part of the image, and the lower part of the texture is filled with white. Please tell me what it could be? How i can fix it?

Answer (score 290):

In your build.gradle(Module:app), add [`android-gif-drawable`](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) as a dependency by adding the following code:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: As of *Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0*, the new command for compiling is `implementation`, so the above line might have to be changed to:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.17'
}
```

---

Then sync your project.
When synchronization ends, go to your layout file and add the following code:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/gif_file"
/>
```

And that's it, you can manage it with a simple ImageView.

Comment: This answer is the best answer and it works very smooth for me, I tried different thing and build classes and unbelievable after I found this.... Thanks mister ;)

Comment: smooth, better then glide for gif

Comment: simple step. this should be the answer. done in minutes

Comment: Not working for me!!! device shows a gray screen Please help.I have inserted the xml code in activity.xml under framelayout

Comment: Shouldn't `pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView` be used instead?

Comment: Its worked awsom, But if i need repeat animation of GIF then what should i do?

Comment: pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView

Comment: Perfect answer but `GifImageView` should be used instead and `android:src` not `android:background`

Comment: NOTE: To make the gif loop, see here https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable/issues/564#issuecomment-403423690

Comment: I recommend against using `pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView`. We pulled it from our app after being continuously confronted with severe security issues and bugs in that library. There are alternatives, see other answers.

Comment: this does not work on notifications right? i guess not since notifications only accept RemoteView?

Comment: Unlike @Manuel, I do recommend `pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView`. I tried the library and it works great with no extra configuration whatsoever. Maybe it has some issues in the past, but currently it does its job very well.

Comment: Any Idea about adding gif in IOS Splash ?

Answer (score 34):

with latest [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library

use Gradle:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

in activity or fragment:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

/* from internet*/
Glide.with(this)
        .load("https://media.giphy.com/media/98uBZTzlXMhkk/giphy.gif")
        .into(imageView);

/*from raw folder*/
Glide.with(this)
        .load(R.raw.giphy)
        .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 20):

Use **VideoView.**

Natively ImageView does not support animated image. You have two options to show animated gif file

1. Use `VideoView`
2. Use `ImageView` and Split the gif file into several parts and then apply animation to it

Comment: How i can use VideoView. Can i show the particular gif image in that VideoView

Comment: How can you use VideoView? If I set the path to a Gif it simply won't work.

Comment: I also did not get how `VideoView` can be used to display the animated GIF ?

Comment: Forget the gif and use a video for animation. I think that is how. Not sure it is an answer to the question though.

Comment: @Sunil Kumar Sahoo you didn't answer to any users'  comment!

Comment: @SunilKumarSahoo You gave the same answer as Armando Esparza Garcia http://stackoverflow.com/a/35273824/247696

Comment: @Flimm May be the issue was same

Answer (score 13):

### Showing GIF In Android

Create **`CustomGifView.java which extends View Class`**

```
 public class CustomGifView extends View {

 private InputStream gifInputStream;
 private Movie gifMovie;
 private int movieWidth, movieHeight;
 private long movieDuration;
 private long mMovieStart;

 public CustomGifView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  init(context);
 }

 public CustomGifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  init(context);
 }

 public CustomGifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, 
   int defStyleAttr) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  init(context);
 }

 private void init(Context context){
  setFocusable(true);
  gifInputStream = context.getResources()
    .openRawResource(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE);

  gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
  movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
  movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
  movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, 
   int heightMeasureSpec) {
  setMeasuredDimension(movieWidth, movieHeight);
 }

 public int getMovieWidth(){
  return movieWidth;
 }

 public int getMovieHeight(){
  return movieHeight;
 }

 public long getMovieDuration(){
  return movieDuration;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

  long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }

        if (gifMovie != null) {

            int dur = gifMovie.duration();
            if (dur == 0) {
                dur = 1000;
            }

            int relTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % dur);

            gifMovie.setTime(relTime);

            gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
            invalidate();

        }

 }

 }
```

Now call this class in your XML

```
 <Your_PackageName.CustomGifView
        android:id="@+id/gifview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

N.P

### Modify AndroidManifest.xml to turn OFF hardwareAccelerated.

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

[Reference](http://android-er.blogspot.it/2014/03/play-animated-gif-with.html)

[Another Tricks](http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.in/2014/04/animated-gif-imageview-library-for.html)

For animation functionality you may visit

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: Working good! Do you know the minimum API level to implement this?

Comment: @KhanSquare Probably 15

Comment: @Lakhan In here it works fine .Okay i will check it again

Comment: @Lakhan Glad to hear . Move ahead .

Comment: as per kimmi dhingra's answer below i gave 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            gifImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

Comment: @Lakhan Thanks for your kind information .I will update

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yeah that will help others too

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya why does the app crash without `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` ?

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest you to use Glide library. To use Glide you need to add this to add these dependencies

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
```

to your grandle (Module:app) file.

Then use this line of code to load your gif image

```
Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.loading).asGif().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).crossFade().into(loadingImageView);
```

[More Information on Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Answer (score 9):

Use Webview to load gif like as

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.gif");
```

Comment: Keep in mind image name is case sensitive. Mine ends with **GIF** and it didn't work when I called `image.gif`

Answer (score 8):

Based on [Ahmad Dwaik 'Warlock's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android#comment28479526_11736861), I have tried the following code and it worked.

1. Use a webview in your xml file, and adjust its position to the place where exactly you were trying to show you .gif image.
2. In your activity initialise this small piece of webview like other views.
3. place the .gif image in assets folder
4. now load the image as if you are loading a url into webview like "diyaWebView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/diya.gif");"
5. you can see your .gif image when you launch the application.

P.S : this things works if you .gif image fits your webview or viceversa else if the image is bigger than the webview the scrollbar gets enabled and user can scroll the image AKA webview. So we need to be careful when we use this, to give proper size to the webview as per image or edit the image that fits your webview.

Answer (score 6):

As [@Ahmad said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android#comment28479526_11736861), you can just use the following code to display a gif!

Just simply pop this code in the onCreate method and you're good to go! Also, place your gif inside the `assets` folder (if you don't have the assets folder, create one under `src/main`)

```
WebView wView = new WebView(this);
wView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/piggy.gif");
setContentView(view);
```

Answer (score 5):

GIFImageView

```
public class GifImageView extends ImageView {

    Movie movie;
    InputStream inputStream;
    private long mMovieStart;

    public GifImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public GifImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GifImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFocusable(true);
        inputStream = context.getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.drawable.thunder);
            byte[] array = streamToBytes(inputStream);
            movie = Movie.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);

    }

    private byte[] streamToBytes(InputStream is) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                1024);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        try {
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) { // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }
        if (movie != null) {
            int dur = movie.duration();
            if (dur == 0) {
                dur = 3000;
            }
            int relTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
            movie.setTime(relTime);
            movie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - 200, getHeight() - 200);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

}
```

In XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="abc" /> 

    <com.example.apptracker.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/gifImageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Java File

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        GifImageView gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifImageView1);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            gifImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
    }
}
```

We need to use `gifImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` as when hardware accelerated enabled, GIF image not work on those device. Hardware  accelerated is enabled on devices above(4.x).

Comment: This doesn't show me anything. Can you please share it on Github?

Answer (score 3):

We can easily add animated gif image on imageview using Ion library.

Tutorial video  :: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqKtpdeIpjA

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_gif);
Ion.with(image).load("http://mygifimage.gif");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can display any gif image via library [Fresco by Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/fresco):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://domain.com/awersome.gif");
final SimpleDraweeView draweeView = new SimpleDraweeView(context);
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);

draweeView.setLayoutParams(params);
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
        .setUri(uri)
        .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
        .build();
draweeView.setController(controller);
//now just add draweeView to layout and enjoy
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

In your build.gradle (project) write  mavenCentral() in the buildscript{} and  allprojects {}. It should look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        **mavenCentral()**
    }
//more code ...
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        **mavenCentral()**
    }
}
```

Then, in build.gradle(module) add in dependencies{} this snippet:

compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.4'

it should look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    **compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.4'**
}
```

Put your .gif image in your drawable folder.
Now go to app > res > layout > activity_main.xml and add this snipped for your .gif:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/YOUR_GIF_IMAGE"
    android:background="#000000" //for black background
    />
```

And you're done :)

Helpful links:
https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOFY0cwNjuk

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly add a dependency in the `module:app` build.gradle file

```
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
```

Then, in the layout file

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mq_app"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Gif's can also be displayed in web view with couple of lines of code and without any 3rd party libraries.
This way you can even load the gif from your SD card. No need to copy images to your Asset folder.

Take a web view.

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageWebView" />
```

Use can open a gif file from SD card not just from asset folder as shown in many examples.

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.imageWebView);
    String  data    = "<body> <img src = \""+ filePath+"\"/></body>";
    // 'filePath' is the path of your .GIF file on SD card.
   webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",data,"text/html","UTF-8",null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced problem to use

```
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
```

And also I could not find the jar file to add to my project. 
So, in order to show gif, I use WebView like this:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<html><body><center><img style='align:center;width:250px; height:250px; border-radius:50%' src='file:///android_asset/loading.gif'/></center></body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Display GIF file in android

Add the following dependency in your build.gradle file.

```
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.0'
```

In the layout -  `activity_xxxxx.xml` file add the `GifImageview` as below.

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
   android:id="@+id/CorrWrong"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="75dp"/>
```

In your Java file , u can access the gif as below.

```
 GifImageView emoji;
 emoji = (GifImageView)findViewById(R.id.CorrWrong);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by atiq.mumtaz on 25.04.2016.
 */
public class GifImage_Player extends Thread
{
    Activity activity;
    ImageView image_view;
    boolean is_running=false;
    int pause_time;
    int[] drawables;

    public GifImage_Player(Activity activity,ImageView img_view,int[] drawable)
    {
        this.activity=activity;
        this.image_view=img_view;
        this.is_running=true;
        pause_time=25;
        this.drawables=drawable;
    }

    public void set_pause_time(int interval)
    {
        this.pause_time=interval;
    }
    public void stop_playing()
    {
        this.is_running=false;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Log.d("Gif Player","Gif Player Stopped");

        int pointer=0;
        while (this.is_running)
        {
           if(drawables.length>0)
           {
             if((drawables.length-1)==pointer)
             {
                 pointer=0;
             }


               try
               {
                   activity.runOnUiThread(new Run(pointer));
                   Thread.sleep(pause_time);
               }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                   Log.d("GifPlayer","Exception: "+e.getMessage());
                   is_running=false;
               }
               pointer++;
           }
        }
        Log.d("Gif Player","Gif Player Stopped");
    }

    class Run implements Runnable
    {
        int pointer;
        public Run(int pointer)
        {
            this.pointer=pointer;
        }
        public void run()
       {
           image_view.setImageResource(drawables[pointer]);
       }
    }
}

/////////////////////////////Usage///////////////////////////////////////




  int[] int_array=new int[]{R.drawable.tmp_0,R.drawable.tmp_1,R.drawable.tmp_2,R.drawable.tmp_3
               ,R.drawable.tmp_4,R.drawable.tmp_5,R.drawable.tmp_6,R.drawable.tmp_7,R.drawable.tmp_8,R.drawable.tmp_9,
                    R.drawable.tmp_10,R.drawable.tmp_11,R.drawable.tmp_12,R.drawable.tmp_13,R.drawable.tmp_14,R.drawable.tmp_15,
                    R.drawable.tmp_16,R.drawable.tmp_17,R.drawable.tmp_18,R.drawable.tmp_19,R.drawable.tmp_20,R.drawable.tmp_21,R.drawable.tmp_22,R.drawable.tmp_23};

GifImage_Player gif_player;             
gif_player=new GifImage_Player(this,(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mygif),int_array);
            gif_player.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fast and Simple for me. no need to add dependencies:**
After 2 days search, finally I found this method that works fine for me, I explained it at: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75334698/1817569) . maybe its useful for someone