# handle gif images in android

Tags: android

In my android application i am using Movie to display gif but the issue i am facing is if i am receiving images with extension .gif with only one frame of image it is displaying blank screen.
Please let me know the better way to display gif in android.
The code i am using is

```
public MYGIFView(Context context, InputStream is, int i, int j,int screenWidth,int screenHeight) {
    super(context);

    //is=context.getResources().openRawResource(red);
    movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
    xcoordinate = i;
    ycoordinate = j;
    viewWidth = screenWidth;
    viewHeight = screenHeight;


    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(viewWidth,viewHeight));

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(movie != null) {
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        int dur = Math.max(movie.duration(), 1); // is it really animated?
        int pos = (int)(now % dur);
        movie.setTime(pos);
        movie.draw(canvas,xcoordinate, ycoordinate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [API demos itself provides a solution](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/BitmapDecode.html) to this.

I think what you are missing is the triggering of this Movie.

Do this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
new Thread() {
    @Override public void run() {
        // ... setup the movie (using the code from above)
        // ... create and display the custom view, passing the movie

        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    view.invalidate();
                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50); // yields 20 fps
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}.start();
```

or as the API demo shows, invalidate the view in the `onDraw()` event itself, causing a redraw till, the movie's duration is over.

Comment: Thread.sleep(50); // yields 20 fps

We need to create a new hell for you

Answer (score 0):

I have tried like this its working gif file run in android.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.gifview;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GifWebView view = new GifWebView(this, "file:///android_asset/earth.gif");
        setContentView(view);
    }



}
```

**GifWebView.java**

```
package com.example.gifview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class GifWebView extends WebView {

    public GifWebView(Context context, String path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context);
        loadUrl(path);
    }

}
```

Note: No need of editing in activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can't load .GIF images directly to Android.

You can trick it by ImageSwitcher or other alternatives. 
Please refer this link too, [Adding gif image in an ImageView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android)