# GIF image doesn't animate in monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

When I add GIF image ImageView it remains constant, i.e. it doesn't animate. Why is it so? What should I do?

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748595/gif-image-doesnt-animate-in-monodroid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general android feature - animated gif's are old tech.

For some workarounds, see

- [Adding gif image in an ImageView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android)
- [Display Animated GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/android-display-animated-gif)