# Animation in Splashscreen [Titanium]

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator, splash-screen

My client wants an animation while the app is loading, something like the Skype App.

Is there a way to do that with Appcelerator ( iOS, Android ) ?
if so, can anybody send me some light ?

Thanks in advance.
Appcelerator Studio 4.9.1.201707200100
SDK 6.1.2GA

Comment: you can use gif image like skype use Picasso or Glide android library. You can see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416383/how-to-play-gif-in-android  . I think this will be help you

Comment: Hi @MahmudurRahman, thanks,  but I'm developing in titanium.

Comment: gif is possible in Titanium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a blank splashscreen and open a fullscreen view with the animation at the beginning that is blocking the screen and shown while you load the app in the background. Most of the time the splashscreen is visible for a seconds so if you fade in or start your animation from white it would look like it is a starting from the beginning.
You can use video (mp4, build in), GIF (https://github.com/AndreaVitale/av.imageview) or a Lottie animation (https://github.com/m1ga/ti.animation).