# Write video in canvas?

Tags: android, canvas

Like we draw image bitmap in canvas. Is there possible to write video and GIF in Canvas?

also I found [How to play GIF in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416383/how-to-play-gif-in-android) this for write GIF.

- I am making PDF From Canvas text and Image are working good as I need. but stuck in video and GIF.

Any Help Accepted.

Comment: Why not do a search on Google? These are the first two items found: http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/ and http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/Drawanimatedgif.htm

Comment: you basically can take the video frame by frame manually drawing them on canvas, but it is going to be too slow.

Comment: @emandt I Already Added Link For GIF which I found.. what about Video?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko is there any othe option to crate video PDF??

Comment: I don't think you can embed a video in the PDF. PDF is static AFAIK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to play video on canvas? Like it's name suggest it is a canvas. Playing a gif is already extending it's limit. Why don't you use video player? I found a good tutorial by **googling for a bit**. [Here is the tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-a-video-player-app-in-android-part-1-5-d95770ef762d) in case google was blocked in your country. And [this library for showing and playing GIF](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

If you try to convert video to pdf then there is absolutely something wrong with your understanding about PDF.

Comment: thank you for you answer. I'll See on this.. you are right may be this concept is wrong to implement in pdf