# Play GIF in custom view class

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, gif

I have a custom class that extends the `View` class. How can I draw a GIF behind other things I am drawing on `Canvas` in the `onDraw` method?

There is a similar question but `Movie` class is deprecated:

[How to play GIF in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416383/how-to-play-gif-in-android)

Comment: Have you tried to load it with Glide?

Comment: I haven't found any example how to draw an image with Glide on the Canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way by loading **GIF** using **[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)** in your `onDraw()` method:

Edit: based on discussion with **@filipst** about loading it on canvas, adding code in `onResourceReady()` method

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    ...
    Glide.with(this.getContext())  // 'this' here is your custom view reference 
        .asGif() // We will define this to tell Glide about it's GIF format to load explicitly
        .load(R.raw.gif_test) // or even put it into drawable R.drawable.git_test
        .into(new SimpleTarget<GifDrawable>() { 
            @Override 
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull GifDrawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super GifDrawable> transition) { 
                resource.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()); // Import to set bounds of canvas to load resource otherwise won't load
                resource.draw(canvas); 
                resource.start();
                //or 
                resource.startFromFirstFrame();
            } 
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Glide.with(this.getContext()).asGif().load("https://media.giphy.com/media/xThtaoctdyU3xlMphe/giphy.gif").into(new SimpleTarget<GifDrawable>() {
            Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull GifDrawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super GifDrawable> transition) {
                resource.draw(c);
            }
        });

It is not drawing anything

Comment: Use `resource.start();` and then set your drawable. check out more http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/431/com/bumptech/glide/load/resource/gif/GifDrawable.html

Comment: I can't draw anything to canvas from onResourceReady. I tried to draw simple circle and it is not showing.

Comment: call `invalidate()` when you make any change to canvas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186929/discussion-between-filipst-and-jeel-vankhede).

Answer (score 0):

you can use Lottie here is the [Library](http://airbnb.io/lottie/android/android.html)

**From XML**

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/animation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/hello_world"
        // or
        app:lottie_fileName="hello_world.json"

        // Loop indefinitely
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        // Start playing as soon as the animation is loaded
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true" />
```

**Programmatically**

```
@BindView(R.id.animation_view)
LottieAnimationView animation_view;

 animation_view.setImageAssetsFolder("images/");
        animation_view.setAnimation(R.raw.lightning_animation);
        animation_view.useHardwareAcceleration(true);
        animation_view.enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove(true);
        animation_view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        animation_view.playAnimation();
```

It's an easy and simple library to use animation like GIF.

Comment: I need to play GIF file, not an animation. And it has to be in onDraw on Canvas

Comment: its also play GIF in the form of JSON

Comment: Basically, GIF is using for animation through the infinite loop if you don't want a loop you can use for a single time but you can easily play GIF for once just convert GIF file into JSON format and use it.

Comment: And is there a way to use it directly on canvas?

Comment: take a look I think there is a way to use canvas [Link1](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web#other-loading-options), [Link2](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/435)