# Use GIF in Custom view that is playable

Tags: android, canvas, android-glide

I have a custom class that extends the View class. How can I draw a GIF behind other things I am drawing on Canvas in the onDraw method?

I got the [solution](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/04/implement-custom-view-to-display.html) by Movie class is deprecated and I didn't able to find their dependency:

I get the similar stackoverflow question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251333/play-gif-in-custom-view-class), I followed their step and got  error that i didn't understand and my app got crash, here the error

[image]

I am expect to get like this screenshot, here image is gif
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't share any code my answer is very high level too.

You can use [android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedImageDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedImageDrawable) (for API >= 28) and [android.graphics.Movie](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie) (for API < 28).

Both classes have a `draw()` method that draws on the given `Canvas`.

Don't forget to call `setBounds()` in case you use the `AnimatedImageDrawable`.

Comment: So far I have used Movie and have problem with adding gif url but works at adding R.raw gif file , not sure what's wrong with Glide, Is there any reference to using AnimatedImageDrawable with gif url and any reference or hint to use gif url in Movie too. For code, it's the same as I use another reference of Stackoverflow same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251333/play-gif-in-custom-view-class

Comment: If you are asking how to play a remote GIF using an `AnimatedImageDrawable` then you will probably need to download the file first.