# How to play gif in android in Api 22

Tags: android, gif

I try to use gif in my android project in api 22 .

I used glide and gifviewer component but not shown in my project and gradle not build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use gradle dependencies, try this instruction that used `InputStream` and `Movie` class: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75334698/1817569). I described it and I think it is useful to play gif animations.