# Getting path of local image instead of URL Android

Tags: android, directory, imageview, gif

I am working with gif images at the moment and have followed the answer from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android)

From this I have the following line of code:

```
    GifWebView view = new GifWebView(this, "http://cdn.lifebuzz.com/images/17487/lifebuzz-35df9a5ee351ae72711e5a293658e319-limit_2000.gif");
```

Now, I  want to download this image, save it locally in the "drawable" folder or "assets" folder and then access it from there.

I have tried downloading the image into the "drawable" folder and trying :

```
    GifWebView view = new GifWebView(this, "@drawable/myimg.gif");
```

I have also tried this:

```
    int imageResource = R.drawable.myimg;

    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);

    String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.myimg;

    GifWebView view = new GifWebView(this, imageUri);
```

Still no luck.

I've tried accessing it from the assets folder but this seemed even more complicated.

I just would like to save it locally and access it locally, I don't really care where it is stored.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

```
public GifWebView(Context context, String path) {

    super(context);        
    loadUrl(path);
}
```

Comment: "save it locally in the "drawable" folder or "assets" folder and then access it from there" no no no, its basically not possible, save it in app's local data path

Comment: do I have to access URL then?

Comment: Where is this local data path, and how would I access it? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: see android.os.Environment

Comment: Why can I not use drawable or assets? I basically want to avoid using internet connection. That is all.

Comment: you can use assets of course but it is read-only beast, you can read from them but cannot insert anything at the runtime

Comment: Yes, I only need to access the image to view on screen. How would I use this file path in the above context?

Comment: so if you have an image place it in some drawable folder, but im confused what do you mean by remote url like cdn.lifebuzz.com/images/17487/lifebuzz-35df9a5ee351ae72711e5a293658e319-limit_2000.gif and that you dont want to use internet?

Comment: aha i see now: what are params of GifWebView? does it only accept some url?

Comment: I have added the constructor for GifWebView in question

Comment: try it with file:/// then

Comment: also you could try  scheme described for AssetFileDescriptor#openAssetFileDescriptor, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openAssetFileDescriptor(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String) i mean SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE one of android.resource://package_name/type/name or android.resource://package_name/id_number

Comment: What exactly would be in the path name beginning with `file:///`, I have tried many ways using Assets folder and none worked. Found about 3 or 4 different potential answers on StackOverflow

Comment: first try one of android.resource://package_name/.. from my last comment, if it doesn't work i am afraid you have to copy your asset to some physical file and use file:///full_file_path

Comment: save it in cache and load from this path, but first you need a class to download the gif image from url

Comment: @pskink It worked - `file:///android_assets/myimg.gif`. Thanks a mill!

Comment: thanks for what? you discovered this: file:///android_assets, not me... :)