# Gif support in React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, gif

React Native of Android don't support GIF?
If I want to add gif support, what should I do?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android

Comment: It should work out of the box... I'm using gifs with no problems on RN 0.18.

Comment: You can use Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide. It is much more faster.

Answer (score 1):

By default the Gif images are not supported in android react native app.
You need to set the following code to display the gif images.
The code:
Open your android/app/build.gradle file add the following code in the place of

```
open android/app/build.gradle add the following  code 

dependencies: { 
  ...
     // For animated GIF support
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:0.11.0'  
    // For WebP support, including animated WebP
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.11.0'  
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:0.11.0' 
    compile  'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:0.11.0'
```

then you need to bundle the app again, You can display the gif images in two ways like this.

```
   1-> <Image source={require('./../images/load.gif')}  style={{width: 100, height: 100 }}/>
   2-> <Image source={{uri: 'http://www.clicktorelease.com/code/gif/1.gif'}}  style={{width: 100, height:100 }}/>
```

I hope it is helpful to others,

Comment: No help in RN0.56