# Adding a GIF to an ImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, animated-gif

what is the most efficient way on adding a gif file in an ImageView in android without using ion library?

anything would help, thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding gif image in an ImageView in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

The most common way I used to see recently is this library 
[Android GIF library](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)
.
You'll insert the animated GIF in your layout.xml in this way

```html
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/left_anim"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/left_anim"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_anim"
    />
```