# Loading gif using Glide from Raw folder

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I am trying to load a gif into ImageView using Glide library. Gif image is in Raw folder. Below is the code :

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .asGif()
            .load(R.raw.tenor)
            .listener(new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                    Log.d("Fragment::","onLoadFailed::" + e.getMessage());
                    Log.d("Fragment::","onLoadFailed::" + e.getCauses());
                    Log.d("Fragment::","onLoadFailed::" + e.getRootCauses());
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Log.d("Fragment::","onResourceReady::" + resource.getFrameCount());
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(mainIv);
```

But it is not loading. Am I missing anything ? It is not giving failed log.

Comment: ple visit http://www.gkmit.co/articles/how-to-display-animated-gif-in-an-android-application and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android

Answer (score 1):

In my case this work:

```
DrawableImageViewTarget target = new DrawableImageViewTarget(myImageView);
Glide.with(context)
     .load(R.drawable.camera_rotate)
     .into(target);
```

My gif in drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

delete asGif ,code as follow:

```
Glide.with(mContext)            
.load(R.raw.tenor)
.listener(new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {
     @Override
     public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        Log.d("Fragment::","onLoadFailed::" + e.getMessage());
        Log.d("Fragment::","onLoadFailed::" + e.getCauses());
        Log.d("Fragment::","onLoadFailed::" + e.getRootCauses());
        return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
        Log.d("Fragment::","onResourceReady::" + resource.getFrameCount());
        return false;
     }
})
.into(mainIv);
```

Comment: Cannot resolve .asGif() method if we change that order

Comment: which version of your glide library?I guess your glide version is less than 4,you can upgrade it and try again.

Comment: I am using implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'

Comment: sorry,it's my mistake I'll post it again,asGif method should delete.