# GIF image is not working in my application

Tags: java, android, gif

Gif doesn't work with my library :

```
implementation 'com.github.Cutta:GifView:1.1'

repositories {
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
```

My layout

```
 <com.cunoraz.gifview.library.GifView
    android:id="@+id/gif1"
    android:layout_width="212dp"
    android:layout_height="132dp"
    app:gif="@drawable/tst1" />
```

My apk stopped and didn't show anything.

Comment: Check this link it might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android

Comment: Instead of app:gif you have to use custom:gif

Comment: Crash log please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

In your gradle add

```
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.5'
```

In your layout add

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:id="@+id/gif"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark"
    />
```

Finally, in your activity add

```
import pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView;
...

GifImageView gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif);
gifImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.giphy);
```

Comment: application has stoped  in run