# How to make animation in android through java

Tags: java, android, animation

I want to have the same effect of animation of the logo as shown in the .gif I don't have any idea about how to create it? Can I make this using Java in Android Studio or some other tool should be used for it?[This is the sample video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0TYI.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35273824/5304075) you can include gif in ImageView to display the animation that you want

Answer (score 0):

To make an animation you can use [Adobe Illustrator](https://www.adobe.com/sea/products/illustrator/free-trial-download.html) and animation can be run with  [Lottie Android](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android).

Answer (score 0):

You can deign animation in environment such as Adobe XD and then generate .json file.
Now by using Lottie library, you can load your animation.