# How do i create this animation?

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to create this animation, i already checked several blogs but did not find one that addresses what i want. Some help would be appreciated thanks. [animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF1di.gif).

Comment: Hi there, please add your current code and also please look at the guidelines on how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/) from airbnb. It's a library that renders affter effects animations in real time. Here's the [setup guide](http://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android)

Answer (score 0):

Creating that kind of animation via code is tedious , if you can find the gif of it you can just add it to the imageview , how you can achieve this you can find on the given link

[Adding gif image in an ImageView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android)