# Adding animation to android

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm not even sure if it is called animation but I couldn't find it anywhere.

In my application, I want to give a star to the users once they finish some activity.

I want to make some animation that will look like this:

https://dribbble.com/shots/2795344-Jump-jump

How can I do something like this on android?

I see different applications in my device that have cool animations and cant figure out how it is done.

Of course, it doesn't have to be that star but anything that will give the same feeling.

Thank you

Comment: One way would be to create a Lottie animation and use the [lottie android library](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) to show it.

Comment: An easy solution is using GIFs. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use Lottie to have sucn an amazing animation ,with just few lines of code.**
For example have a look here -> https://lottiefiles.com/search?q=star&category=animations

Let me make you understand how to get started with it....

(1) Add dependency for Lottie

```
 implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion'
```

(2) Add lottie view in layout

(3) Download animation and use it...

[Reference Blog](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi90NSX_v7wAhVqwTgGHcHLAVsQFjANegQIHRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.mindorks.com%2Fgetting-started-with-lottie-animation-in-android&usg=AOvVaw3nhVunDH4bWotx5NdvqwIX)

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Comment: Wish I knew it earlier. Will try it right now. Thank you. Is there a way to make the animation appear and disappear after X time as well? Also, Is there anything needed with regard to proguard? couldn't find anything with it.

Comment: Always welcome . Yes you have animation listener... You can use that and as far as I know ..  nothing to do with progaurd.

Comment: Could you please upvote this answer...? If you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the Motion Layout

For more information you can check the [official Motion Layout documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout)