# How to take input gif from keyboard and show in chat like Whatsapp?

Tags: android, android-studio, logic, mobile-application, android-input-method

I am working on a social media application. Where user can view and reply to their story then they can chat.

**Handling chatting on :**

```
public class ReplyBottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
 
// kodes...

}
```

I am using ***EditText*** to take **input** and ***TextView*** to **show** it.

Now I want to add gif feature in my application. Please any suggestion?

Comment: maybe it help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736861/15409326). good lucky

Comment: Sorry, it's not. I am asking here to take input from keyboard not static gifs to show. Anyway thanks  for you suggestion @ACTPOHOM.