# How to show GIF with Animation using GPHSettings & GPHMediaView in XML and kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, animated-gif, giphy

In my scenario when user click button it's navigate to next screen and If user click icon have to show Bottom sheet.
In the bottom sheet have to show GIF with it's animation.

And user can choose any GIF they want. I wanna use GPHMediaView to show the GIF not image View. The isuue is GIF Animation is Working in Dev Environment. But when i run the Application in Test environment the GIF Is Not Working.

Comment: what's the reason of not using ImageView?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533942/adding-gif-image-in-an-imageview-in-android

Comment: It's app requirement @KamalNayan. But now i got output. the issue is some permission issue. Thanks for your interest to help.

Comment: Thanks for your interest to help @Community. The issue is the GIF is not working only in test environment. Now it's working after changing the Some permission property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that GIF animation not shown Only in test Environment is - Because of some permission property issue. After made changes in Proguard and build gradle property the GIF animation is working fine in both environment.