# Adding a gif image as an android loading icon?

Tags: android, icons, loading, gif

I am currently trying to take an animated gif image and use it as an android loading icon. In other words, I am trying to take a gif and use it when I am waiting for a different screen to load. I realize I am able to do this with a series of pictures, but is it possible to do it with just an individual gif image? I'm really not sure how to do this.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be exactly what you're looking for but you can definitely use an "image sequence" type of animation to as a loading screen.

Check the answer of this other question: [Custom Progress Dialog With Squre Image Rotation With AsynTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900747/custom-progress-dialog-with-squre-image-rotation-with-asyntask)

As for the GIF part, this might help as well: [Problem with Animated gif on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691726/problem-with-animated-gif-on-android)

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is what I am looking for, thank you! I am just wondering if that custom progress dialog is doable with just one gif image.

Comment: Yes, using a single GIF image is possible using several methods, the easiest being a WebView that loads the GIF file from Assets... Using a frame.html with an IFrame that loads the file alongside the image in the Assets folder of your application.  Another way is to add the gif to Drawables and load it using ( Movie )