# phonegap :: animated gif on gmap

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps

I'm developing an app that displays in a gmap animated icon markers (gifs). I have made it work on the Windows environment with "icon" and "optimized" options of the Marker, but it doesn't load properly (not even then image).

I have read here
[Problem with Animated gif on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691726/problem-with-animated-gif-on-android) that Android doesn't handle properly gifs. Is there any way of using a gif as google marker in Android?

Thanks,
xavi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the Google Maps Android API, you cannot find any documentation about GIF as [marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker). So the alternative way is to use animation on marker.

Here is a [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/01/implement-bouncing-marker-for-google.html) on how to use animation on marker, it implements a bouncing marker for the Google Maps Android API v2. It also contains a YT [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siE7-zQB6ko) that shows how the marker move in your device.

For more information about animation in markers, check this SO question:

- [How to animate marker in android map api V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872803/how-to-animate-marker-in-android-map-api-v2)
- [Animating markers on Google Maps V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864664/animating-markers-on-google-maps-v2)
- [Problem with Animated gif on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691726/problem-with-animated-gif-on-android)