# How to set GIF image as the google maps marker for the Android and iOS platforms (Ionic Framework)?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, ionic3, google-maps-markers

I want to set a **GIF image as a map marker** representing specific places on the google maps. I have used *ionic cordova* environment to build the project. Please find the environment setup below:

li packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v8.8.1
npm        : 2.15.12 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /Users/MP-36/Users/MP-36/Library/Android/sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Also, I have used **cordova plugin googlemaps** to render a map into my app.
Plugin Details:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="^2.3.6">
   <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value=“#” />
   <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value=“#” />
</plugin>
```

The map renders as expected but from the improvements points of view, I need to add gif image as a marker. I have tried different solutions to satisfy the same but not able to make it.

**Solution Tried:**

Adding a script tag into the *index.html* file and setting the *optimized* property to *false*.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"> 
</script>

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!',
        icon: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/outsavvy/website/loading.gif",
        optimized: false
});
```

**Result:**
This would probably work on the web view, not for the Android and iOS platforms. For the Android and iOS platforms, I was *able to see the static image i.e the single frame from the GIF image*, not the entire animation.

There is any way to add a GIF marker which supports for both the Android and iOS platforms or to create a custom marker and add animation to the same?
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: check this link, it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39096058/2919483

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phonegap :: animated gif on gmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068199/phonegap-animated-gif-on-gmap)

Comment: @StevenScott I want to set the GIF image through Ionic framework not the phonegap one mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068199/phonegap-animated-gif-on-gmap. Can you please direct me with Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

Answer as author of cordova-plugin-googlemaps.
cordova-plugin-googlemaps does not support GIF animated image for marker, because native APIs do not support it.